# Prompting with JavaScript before deletion deson't work

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql

I have a page where I list the content of a table in my database, and I am trying to add a button to delete a row. I looked it up and used JavaScript to do it, but it doesn't work.

```
//Deletion
if (isset($_GET['sup']))
{
    $sup = $_GET['sup'];
    $sql=mysql_query("delete from UCH where id=".$sup);
}

//Fecthing data
$sql='SELECT * FROM uch';
$req=mysql_query($sql);

//Starting the table
$table='<table  cellspacing="0" width=100%><tr><td>N°</td><td>Eleve</td><td>Ecole</td><td>Classe</td><td>Mail</td><td>Examen</td><td>Preparation</td>';
$i=0;
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($req))
{
    //Alternating the table's background color every other row
    $i++;
    if ($i%2==1 )
    {
        $couleurLigne= 'style="background-color: #b7b6b6;"';
    }
    else
    {
        $couleurLigne = 'style="background-color: #e8e0e0;"';
    }

    //Converting bit-type data
    if ($data['preparation']=='1') $prepa="oui";
    else $prepa="non";

    //Introducing the data from the database and the rest of the table
    $table.='<tr '.$couleurLigne.'><td>'.$i.'</td><td>'.$data['prenom'].' '.$data['nom'].'</td><td>'.$data['ecole'].'</td><td>'.$data['classe'].'</td><td>'.$data['email']
    .'</td><td>'.$data['examen'].'</td><td>'.$prepa.'</td>
    <td><a href="admin_U-CH.php?sup='.$data['id'].'" onclick="return confirm("Etes-vous sur(e) de vouloir supprimer cette entree ?")"><div style="color: red;">X</div></a></td><tr>';
}

$table.='</table>';
echo $table;
```

That last cell contains an `X`, that is a link to delete the row.

As it is, it doesn't prompt me and reload the page with the `$_GET` value, but it still doesn't delete anything.

P.-S: Most of the non-code stuff is in french, sorry if I don't translate everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the double quotes in your confirmation text, change them to single quotes (easy) or escape them with `\` character (maybe you will get confused here):

`onclick="return confirm('Etes-vous sur(e) de vouloir supprimer cette entree ?')"`

The long explanation is that since you use **double quotes** for wrapping the `oncilck` method you must not use them again inside the wrapped text, unless they are escaped. But using single quotes is easiest.

**Nota bene:** Since you may find yourself using weird non-English characters (French in this case) - it is always a good idea to check your text sentences before usage inside scripts - and if you have wrapped the text in single quotes (in `onclick` method) make sure you escape any single quote which appear in text, for example `'what\'s up'` or `'c\'est la vie'`